# Change the image names stored in Liferay AWS S3 Document Library repository

Tags: amazon-s3, liferay

I need to store image name as it is (name of the image) in the Liferay 6.2 CE S3 Document Library repository.

As an example my current image tag is,

```
<img alt="Image" src="/image/journal/article?img_id=23704&amp;t=1445229592755">
```

I need to store ,

```
<img alt="my_ship" src="/image/journal/article/23704/my_ship.jpg">
```

What are the necessary changes need to do in the Liferay? Do I need to write a Liferay Hook application?